# Can "damage over time" effects stack in pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

For example, lets say that a Pokemon is poisoned (or burnt) while a sandstorm rages and is attacked with Bind, do all three damages stack on top of each other after the "turn" is over?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, repeating damage from different sources stack. The example Pokemon will take damage from poison/burn, sandstorm, and Bind separately. This is easily reproducible.